# Calculating or estimating implicit fees from 401k

Tags: 401k, fees, expense-ratio

I'm looking at my most recent Account Statement from a previous employer's 401k.

There's a lil table on the first page with the opening balance, the range of dates that pertain to the statement, how many deposits, withdrawals, `Fees/Expenses` and Gains/Loses. The `Fees/Expenses` is listed as `$0.00`

Later in the statement is a caveat...

> **Your Fee and Expense Details** You didn't have any transaction fees or expenses deducted from your account during this period. However,
>   some of the plan's administrative expenses for the period may have
>   been paid from fees from one or more of the plan's investment funds.
>   These expenses are included in the expense ratio (total annual
>   operating expenses) provided in the applicable investment fund
>   disclosures.

I browsed a handful of prior statements, even during the time I was employed with the former company, and they all list `Fees/Expenses   $0.00`.

Is there a way to convert that expense ratio with my account balance into effective dollars paid as if there were a direct fee?

What's the motivation behind this payment strategy, seems to just obscure things, but maybe it simplifies things? What's the deal here?

Comment: did you read the "applicable investment fund disclosures"?

Answer (score 2):

TD Ameritrade offers a free tool to calculate the your total 401(k) expenses, including fund management fees.  It is available here: https://www.tdameritrade.com/retirement-planning/retirement-resources/401k-fee-analysis.page

Disclosure: I'm a financial advisor at [Baker, Brose, & Mitsutome Wealth Management](https://investwithintegrity.com/).  We custody our client's assets, including rollover IRA accounts, at TD Ameritrade.